# Save data in json format using php

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I wanted to save the data in this format into database `option` field:

```
{"type":"type_value"}
```

I am getting data in post varaibles like this

```
$type_value = $request->input('type_value');
$type = $request->input('type');
```

How Can I save this in database?
I have tried this

```
$data['options'] = array($type,$type_value);
```

But by this it is saving in this format:

```
["Qualifiers","1"]
```

I even tried doing this:

```
$data['options'] = json_encode(array($type,$type_value));
```

Instead it is saving like this

```
"[\"Qualifiers\",\"1\"]"
```

how can I do this?

Comment: serialize it and save it and then unserialize it when trying to access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change your array definition. Your array considers 2 different elements i.e `type` and `type_value`. So just make your array with key value pair and you are all set.

```
json_encode(array($type => $type_value))
```

Check this :- [Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/PruCm)